# Save Attachments from Outlook with ReceivedTime on file name

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory, attachment

I'm trying to create a macro where I can save the attachments from an email. The problem I'm currently having is that I want the macro to add the ReceivedTime of the email on the file name it saves (i.e.: File TESTSHEET.xls was received on 2016-01-01 3:02AM. I want the saved file to show 201601010302AM-TESTSHEET.xls or something similar)

Here's my current code:

```
Public itm As Object

Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk()
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
        saveFolder = "C:\Users\Username\Documents\TEST REPORTS"
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile objAtt.DisplayName
    Next objAtt
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objDate As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim StrDate As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
Set itm = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim CurrentMsg As Outlook.MailItem


 ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\TEST REPORTS\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            ' Combine with the path to the Save folder.
            StrDate = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
            strFile = strFolderpath & StrDate & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            MsgBox strFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: We know what you want it to do, but what *does* this code do?

Comment: The filename prefix format should use `"yyyymmddhhmm-"`. But you should do another check if there is a file of the resultant name exists. Also You don't need the Outlook App if this macro is to be executed in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Use objMsg not itm.

```
' StrDate = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
 StrDate = Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
```

Additionally drop other code with itm and as well objOL

```
' Set itm = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
' Dim CurrentMsg As Outlook.MailItem

' On Error Resume Next
' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
' Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Do not use On Error Resume Next until you know what you are doing.